Started bounty on someone else's interesting question, then question has been closed before end of bounty
I have found this interesting question (I am not the author) : Cut a video in between key frames without re-encoding the full video using ffpmeg?.
It was quite upvoted, which shows interest by other people, but as it lacked a very good answer, I decide to spend 250 points for a bounty on this question. Quite surely, a good answer for this post would use scripting/programming to achieve OP's goal.
Later, sadly, it has been closed just after I started the bounty because "not about programming". This is debatable here because often ffmpeg-related questions involve scripting (e.g. Python scripting) to achieve a particular goal.
Question: are my 250 points lost? The bounty is useless since the question is now closed. Or could we reopen at least until the bounty finishes?
Instead of closing, I would have suggested to wait that the bounty finishes before closing. Indeed:

an OP has written the post
19 people have upvoted to show it's useful
someone has decided to spend 250 points to help improve the knowledge base
are good arguments that we can wait a few more days before closing, especially since the "out-of-topic" argument is not 100% clear.

Note: linked to Can I Offer a Bounty on a Closed Question? but not duplicate.

Note that closing bountied question has been purposely added recently.

The question is about usage of the CLI so that question is off-topic (not going to be reopened unless it's used programmatically)

While I do tend to be on the conservative side of the "what is a programming question" debate, this question is about usage of a video editing tool. It is unequivocally not about programming, in any sense of the word. Just because an answer could, theoretically, use programming as part of a solution, does not make the question itself on topic.

I will also point out your bounty notice explicitly requested "a feature integrated in ffmpeg" and made no mention of programming.

please do not change the question scope once it has been answered. also, please do not use "edit" headers. if you want to ask about migrating the linked question, you should ask a new question.

Please don't re-edit my question @yivi, I would like to keep this final edit, it does not change "the question scope" at all, it only adds a suggestion for those interested who would help to keep this question alive (somewhere else).

Please @yivi, could you let me decide what I want to state in my question? :)

It does change the scope. Your question is about a bounty and about a closed question. Migration is a different topic. Since I have posted an answer, I do not like having the question being changed after the fact.

It is a side remark at the end, it is not a change of scope. Please don't edit my question @yivi.

@Basj It's pretty well established you do not change questions after they've been answered, so sorry but no. Also, please do not use "edit" headers.

"could we migrate it to SuperUser" nope that questions around 3 years old that's past the question age allowed for migration.

No, thanks. No offense taken. I don't mind edits, but I don't mind the question being changed in a way that makes it look like I ignored part of it.

@yivi I don't see a huge issue with Basj' edit. It doesn't really change the underlying question. The answer to the edited request is a simple "no, it's not possible". At the very least, flagging for a moderator rather than continuing a dozen rollbacks is probably preferable at this point...

@TylerH It's out of scope. It requires orthogonal tags. It has already been answered by three users.

@yivi you can give me advice like 'please don't you header "edit"' in your posts, but you cannot force me follow this rule ;) There are hundreds of thousands of questions on SO with "Edit: ..." at the end :) so I am not forced to adhere to your wording choices to remove my "edit" paragraph :) No offense again, but come on :)

And when willing users find them, they fix them. Same as spelling mistakes. :)

Haha sure, @yivi, I do it as well, but when I see that OP specifically wanted to add something at the end, only for those interested (here this edit is a side-remark, a call if people are interested in a migration, it's not a "change of scope"), I respect their choice of not wanting being edited :)

It is a change of scope. It's unrelated to the question, which is about a bounty. It's completely unrelated. If it's a "side-remark", then it doesn't really belong to the question.

But you can't decide for me how to do the wording of my question @yivi, come on :) I have seen thousands of questions with side remarks at the end, and everyone is happy about it. Please respect my choice of editing my own question with my own words as side-remarks? You cannot decide so unilaterally those things?

I stand with @yivi's edit here: The remark is a request for this to be migrated, which #1 it shouldn't be, and #2 is not central to the post at all. It's meta commentary which has no place in the question body.

There were already two answers that existed before your edit. Neither addressed the edit before it was made and now that it's there - the answers are incomplete. So, yes we can decide what is in scope or not of your question.

@Spevacus even if I am wrong (which I totally accept I may be), on meta SO, we should let the decision of the wording of a question to OP, no?

Actually, we can change a post against the author wishes. It's the way the site is built and is meant to work. No, an author does not have ultimate decision power over the "wording of their own posts". If someone keeps reverting helpful edits, no matter if it's because "it's their choice of wording", mods should intervene and lock it up. I stopped simply because I don't want to waste more time, but you are simply wrong on this. Bye.

@Basj The wording? Sure. The content of it entirely? No. We edit out thanks/taglines/salutations all the time, as well as content that's not central to the question like here.

"but you cannot force me follow this rule" Yes, we can. You are in the wrong & we can flag a mod.

"But you can't decide for me how to do the wording of my question @yivi, come on" - that's precisely how edits work. When you post on SE, you also grant other people permission to edit. You're not entitled to your post remaining in the exact same format it was posted. Don't roll back again; the edit you added is either a flag or a new question, but in this case, it doesn't matter. The post is far too old to migrate; not because policy, but because the system doesn't allow migrating posts that are more than 60 days old. The question stays closed,

and bounties are non-refundable anyway


Quite surely, a good answer for this post would use scripting/programming to achieve OP's goal.

If that's the case then why does your bounty description explicitly ask for the opposite:

Or a solution in one single call of ffmpeg? Or maybe a feature integrated in ffmpeg that does all these steps automatically?

A command-line call or "integrated feature" of ffmpeg is not a programming matter. Neither the question, nor the existing answers, nor your call for additional answers are related to programming. Please do ask this question on Superuser, instead, as I'm sure it is a useful one!

Thank you for your answer! Since this question is useful for OP, for 19 people, and for me who bountied it, could we migrate it to superuser while bountied? Having this question closed on SO is making it in a dead state. Migrated on SuperUser, it could be very useful (with its history an current answers). What do you think?

@Basj Unfortunately migration is system-restricted (meaning even moderators cannot overcome it) by age. Once a question is older than I think 60 days, it cannot be migrated. You could theoretically ask the same question on another site. That's generally frowned upon (except I think in the foreign-language Stack Overflow sites), but in this case since the question is closed, appropriate quoting/rephrasing (to avoid plagiarism) would probably be OK. I would beware of duplicating an existing ffmpeg question on Superuser already asking for the same thing, though.

Thank you for this info @TylerH, I did not know that. So basically it seems pretty complex to have a migration, complex to have a new question on SU with so many inputs from different people. Basically a good opportunity to improve our knowledge base about an excellent tool (ffmpeg) has been ... lost. I totally agree the rules are ok, but in this particular case (where the initial question was good), it's sad to see a loss of knowledge... Anyway, I will forget about it :)

@Basj There is no loss of knowledge. The question is closed, but that doesn't make it disappear. Likewise it will always exist in the site data dumps or any direct archive.org backups of that page. It simply cannot have more knowledge added to it while it exists here on Stack Overflow, because it's not about programming, and Stack Overflow is a programming site. There's nothing stopping anyone, though, from making a new post on Superuser, referencing or quoting the relevant content from it and its answers, and asking whether there's a single-line command or built-in feature there on SU.

@Basj also have a look at this post: Why is FFmpeg better discussed at Super User?


are my 250 points lost? The bounty is useless since the question is now closed.

The bounty will still drive more attention to the question. If users think the question is on-topic, it could actually be reopened thanks to the additional attention a bounty brings.

Or could we reopen at least until the bounty finishes?

No, voting to reopen should be done only if the question is on-topic, not because it has a bounty posted on it.

Instead of closing, I would have suggested to wait that the bounty finishes before closing. Indeed:

an OP has written the post
19 people have upvoted to show it's useful
someone has decided to spend 250 points to help improve the knowledge base are good arguments that we can wait a few more days before closing, especially since the "out-of-topic" argument is not 100% clear.


None of these is an argument against closing a question. If you are going to argue about closing a question, please focus the arguments on the question scope, and how the question adheres or not to the site's rules.

Note that while the ability to close bountied questions has been added recently, the claim that the bounty and closure features are "orthogonal" does not seem to be (currently) 100% true, as you cannot start a bounty on a closed question.

"you cannot start a bounty on a closed question." Probably a bug/oversight that should be corrected. If users want to spend reputation on a closed question, I don't see why they should not be able to. One of the prescribed bounty reasons is "reward an existing answer" which doesn't require a question to be open at all the fulfill.

Probably, @TylerH. Which is why I put "currently" there, since I expect a newly released feature could very easily change in the near future. Or maybe the features are not meant to be fully orthogonal, which could also be fine.

Sad story. Now we have a closed, dead, unsalvageable, unmigratable question. I don't really mind, because it was even not my own question. I just started a bounty for the collective potential gain of knowlege about this on a popular question. But now it seems that a strict application of a strict new rule about allowing closing of bountied question is the über-most important thing for SO, so let it be! "Hurrah, this question is closed and dead. Hurrah this meta SO is now locked. The collective knowledge about ffmpeg has not increased, but the most important is the rules, yeepee!". Good bye.

"this meta SO is now locked" if you request a mod (or flag for the same) that you want to make a case for reopening the question being discussed and you won't get into another edit war they'll probably remove the lock.

@Basj You are conflating two separate, unrelated things. The meta question was locked just because you continued to change the question after it was answered, despite being advised not to. Please, do not start again here. The question cannot be migrated, but if you want to make the case how the question is on-topic in SO, or could be salvaged to be made on-topic for SO, please post a new question (and stick to that topic only).

@yivi. The two things are somehow related: very strict application of rules for nothing useful. Whether my edit was ultimately useful or not is not really important, it did not do any harm (as confirmed by someone else's comment). What strikes me is your obstination in modifying my own question. I totally agree that's permitted by SO rules (I know SO well too), and often it's useful. But here that's just ... strange! Anyway, what a waste of time and potential knowledge. We have discussed about nothing during pages, and wasted a good opportunity to increase collective knowlege about ffmpeg.

The ability of closing a bountied question is something that has recently been added. Previously bountied questions could not be closed, which meant that a question that was off-topic and had been missed could no longer be closed (as it should be) without moderator attention; this was a frustration for the community. Bountying a question brings that question additional attention, so if you are bountying a question you should make sure that it's on-topic and answerable (such as gives all the required details, or an MRE where needed) before you do, as it could easily be closed now if it's not.
If a question if closed, your bounty is not lost though; you have the option of awarding existing answers (and if those answers get votes it may be automatically awarded) and the question might be able to be made on-topic. In this specific case, however, it likely is from the perspective of attracting a new answer; I can't really see how a question on a CLI application could be made on-topic for Stack Overflow.

As the first (I believe) close-vote, I'll explain that this was one of a number of ffmpeg questions that I voted to close yesterday.  I'd previously found a couple like it over the last few weeks, and I decided to do some clean-up on the tag.  I barely made a dent in the number of off-topic questions in the tag, but this was one of the ones that came up yesterday.
While I believe that allowing off-topic, bountied questions to be closed is a (really) good change, I do think that the bounty should be automatically refunded when this happens (edit based on comments: at least when there have been no new answers). That would be a reasonable feature request, IMHO.
I don't, however, think that the question should be reopened, and (given the age) there's no way for it to be migrated, unfortunately.

"While I believe that allowing off-topic, bountied questions to be closed is a (really) good change,I do think that the bounty should be automatically refunded when this happens" This feels a bit too much. Bounties are there to get attention and attract answers, and a question getting closed does not mean there wasn't already a gain from the bounty.

@MisterMiyagi True, perhaps there was a gain (i.e., a new answer between the time the bounty being offered and the question being closed), perhaps (as in this case) not.  So perhaps an "automatic" action if there have been no new answers?

Previously, a moderator would refund a bounty to close a question out of scope.  I am torn; I believe users would not bounty out-of-scope questions, and if they do, they should live with the loss of reputation. A refund of a bounty question is rare. However, I would be willing to support ending the bounty and refunding it based on when the question was closed. If for instance the question was closed 5 minutes after it was bountied I would support a refund, if the question was closed 6 days 12 hours after it was bountied, getting an answer to a bountied question was never guaranteed.

I think we need more clarity on what ffmpeg questions specifically are on topic. It's not your average command-line program, after all.

@KarlKnechtel Agreed (after some thought). When I first read your comment, I thought it was pretty clear in most cases, but then I switched over to a browser tab I hadn't closed out yet, and  saw this question. Now I'm starting to second-guess my vote. While the question is purely about ffmpeg, is it possible to consider a series of filters to be similar to a "pipeline" that processes text using (e.g.) sed and would be on-topic in the context of a script? Does ffmpeg have its own "scripting language" in how filters (et. al.) are combined?

@KarlKnechtel I would ask what you consider an "average" command-line program. All command-line programs are "average" in the sense that they all are normally interacted with via CLI. As for which ones are on-topic, I would suggest any that involve calling or invoking ffmpeg itself or ffmpeg commands programmatically. Similar to how Windows Task Scheduler is not a programming tool so questions about simply using it are off-topic, but interacting with a scheduled task in it programmatically via C# or PowerShell or whatever are on-topic.

@NotTheDr01ds No, it doesn't have a scripting language. It only has a list of commands/flags you can attach when calling ffmpeg.exe from a CLI that are all under the -flag nomenclature.

Better to ask a stupid question that at least gets people talking rather than saying nothing at all: what exactly would be an on-topic question using the ffmpeg tag? I've been browsing a little and I think I can blow my entire stock of close votes in that tag very easily...

@TylerH in terms of the complexity of command-line arguments offered and the extent to which users typically expect to be able to customize the behaviour.

@KarlKnechtel There's no capacity for complexity when it comes to command-line arguments. Just the number of them used. That's what separates command line commands from programming.

@Gimby If you have a program you are writing that calls ffmpeg.exe and perhaps inserts dynamic flags or something like that, perhaps.
